# Debugging with Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, debugging, tomcat

I am trying to test a (Spring-based) WAR I just wrote and am deploying it to `TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/` and then starting tomcat.  After a minute or so it is obvious the WAR is not running (because it should be consuming messages off an ActiveMQ queue...and its not). I look at the standard output from the console and see:

```
INFO: Deploying web application archive Optimizer.war
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
23 [Thread-2] INFO org.apache.camel.spring.handler.CamelNamespaceHandler - OSGi environment not detected.
Jan 19, 2012 10:54:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jan 19, 2012 10:54:20 AM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [184] milliseconds.
Jan 19, 2012 10:54:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/Optimizer] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Here is my `log4j.properties` file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%c] [%t] (%F:%L) %-5p %c %x - %m%n
log4j.logger.org.milyn=INFO
log4j.logger.org.exolab.castor=INFO
log4j.logger.org.castor.core=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.digester=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache=INFO
log4j.logger.org.springframework=INFO
log4j.logger.com.ibatis=INFO
log4j.logger.java.sql.Connection=INFO
log4j.logger.java.sql.PreparedStatement=INFO
log4j.logger.java.sql.ResultSet=INFO
log4j.logger.java.sql.Statement=INFO
```

And here is my `web.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns    /j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

    <!-- The display name of this web application -->
    <display-name>Optimizer</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/optimizer-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

For one I'd like to know how to make my app/Tomcat more verbose so I can see what's really going on here (and please note, the Tomcat console and corresponding `catalina.log` are the only sources I have for debugging... can't run this from Eclipse workbench because there is no `main` entry point, just `web.xml`).

I suspect something is failing in `web.xml` or perhaps my Spring config file. And I wouldn't mind debugging my config file if I could just get any sort of indication in the logs/error messages as to what is preventing my app from starting up.

Any ideas/hints/suggestions as to start the process of figuring out whats going wrong are *enormously appreciated*! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Context [/Optimizer] startup failed due to previous errors, says your project Optimizer didn't start. Did you check server logs?

Comment: "Error listenerStart" - well, the only listener is the ContextLoaderListener. And before that, we see a log4j error message about a ContextLoader. So the first thing to do is figure out why the Spring classes can't get their logging configured. Once that's fixed, maybe you'll get some useful information in the logger output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually run the entire application from within your IDE if you want, instead of launching Tomcat externally.  However, you then run into the issue that you are to working off your war file, but rather from your .class files (compiled in your workspace).  Additionally, you are not testing if Tomcat is causing any deployment errors either.

I don't remember offhand what the Tomcat error file is, but there are other log files you can check out in the tomcat/log directory as well that will provide with a little additional information.

To launch Tomcat in eclispe, you need to create a new Java runtime configuration.
Specify main class as `org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap`
Program Arguments: [-config ] start
VM Args: as you see fit, but perhaps -Xmx512m, etc...
Working Directory (I usually point to the Tomcat/work directory, if memory serves).

You will also need to add the Tomcat jars (found in tomcat/lib and tomcat/bin) to the classpath under Bootstrap entries).

Once you do that, you should be able to launch tomcat as a java app from within Eclipse, and then you can actually debug step by step the exact process.

NOTE: I'm providing this config information from memory.  I don't remember the exactly path for workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely add a log appender for spring. With the appender you can specify additional log files for specific listeners and appenders. Check out this forum post for more help:
[refer this link](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?11733-Spring-Framework-DEBUG-logging-with-Log4J)

Edit: Examples
Spring appender to a different file:

```
<appender name="SpringAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <param name="file" value="C:/logs/Spring.log"/>
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p %l - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Heres the spring logger / listener set at the debug level.

```
<logger name="org.springframework" additivity="false">
    <level value="debug" />
    <appender-ref ref="SpringAppender" />
</logger>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael! Could I just turn these into `spring-appender.xml` and `spring-logger.xml` (respectively) and put them on the classpath? If so would there be any other configuration necessary to wire up my app with these two files? Thanks again!

Comment: I don't have experience doing that exactly, I usually have one log4j.xml file that is in the classpath that defines all of my logging needs.